# Modularizing golang package using interfaces

Tags: go

I am learning golang and in the process of trying to wrap my head around interfaces and how to use them for unit testing.

I currently have a `main.go` which calls another package: `packageName` that I wrote.

Currently in `main.go`, I use package like this:

```
package main 

import (
  ...
  ./packageName 
)

func main () {
  var1 := "test"
  str1 := packageName.Func1(var1)

  var2 := "sample"
  str2 := packageName.Func2(var2)
}
```

and `packageName` is:

```
package packageName

import (
  "os"
  "net/http"
)

func Func1 (str string) string {
  resp,err := http.get("www.something.com")
  return resp.string() // or something along these lines
}

func Func2 (str string) string {
  sampleFile, sampleFileErr := os.OpenFile(str, os.O_CREATE, 0600)
  return "done"
}
```

After reading about testing and interfaces, it seems like I have to rewrite everything using interfaces so it can be unit tested (more modular).

---

My question, is how do I do this properly. Do I put all external library calls into one interface, and then make all functions in the package part of one struct?
example:

```
package packageName

import (
  "os"
  "net/http"
)

type External interface {
  urlGet(string) (*http.Response, error)
  OpenFile(string, int, os.FileMode) (*os.File, error)
}

func New() ExternalSt {
  return ExternalSt{}
}

struct ExternalSt struct {}

func (ExternalSt) urlGet(str string) *http.Response {
  return http.get(str)
}

func (ExternalSt) OpenFile (str string, flags int, perms os.FileMode) (*os.File, error) {
  return os.OpenFile(str, flags, perms)
} 

func (e ExternalSt) Func1 (str string) string {
  resp,err := e.urlGet("www.something.com")
  // do some other stuff
  return resp.string() // or something along these lines
}

func (e ExternalSt) Func2 (str string) string {
  sampleFile, sampleFileErr := e.OpenFile(str, os.O_CREATE, 0600)
  // do some other stuff
  return "done"
}
```

and then main would be:

```
package main 

import (
  ...
  ./packageName 
)

func main () {
  test := packageName.New()
  var1 := "test"
  str1 := test.Func1(var1)

  var2 := "sample"
  str2 := test.Func2(var2)
}
```

With the above implementation I don't even need the interface, but i'm guessing it would come in handy when Im doing unit tests and need to implement my own mock functions under a test interface to call during testing.

**OR**

should I create an interface with all the external functions, but pass the new instance I create into the functions as a parameter [similar to here](https://medium.com/dm03514-tech-blog/you-are-going-to-need-it-using-interfaces-and-dependency-injection-to-future-proof-your-designs-2cf6f58db192). Ex:

```
package main 

import (
  ...
  ./packageName 
)

func main () {
  var test packageName.External
  var1 := "test"
  str1 := packageName.Func1(test, var1)

  var2 := "sample"
  str2 := packageName.Func2(test, var2)
}
```

and the package:

```
package packageName

import (
  "os"
  "net/http"
)

type External interface {
  urlGet(string) (*http.Response, error)
  OpenFile(string, int, os.FileMode) (*os.File, error)
}

func New() ExternalSt {
  return ExternalSt{}
}

struct ExternalSt struct {}

func (ExternalSt) urlGet(str string) *http.Response {
  return http.get(str)
}

func (ExternalSt) OpenFile (str string, flags int, perms os.FileMode) (*os.File, error) {
  return os.OpenFile(str, flags, perms)
} 

func Func1 (e External, str string) string {
  resp,err := e.urlGet("www.something.com")
  // do some other stuff
  return resp.string() // or something along these lines
}

func Func2 (e External, str string) string {
  sampleFile, sampleFileErr := e.OpenFile(str, os.O_CREATE, 0600)
  // do some other stuff
  return "done"
}
```

The second option doesn't seem to work very well as I keep getting an error

```
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation
```

but I need more of an understanding of interfaces.

Regardless, I cannot seem to understand which of the 2 options are best to go with. 
Or are both these options completely wrong.

**NOTE:** I'm aware the syntax of the above code is incorrect, and will probably not compile, just looking for an approach here.

Comment: You don't need to write interfaces to unit test. You are overcomplicating the problem. Do you need to mock anything in your code for testing? If you need to unit test a function making http calls, you can use httptest package to create a server. If you need to open a file, put that file into testdata and don't hardcode paths.

Comment: It's not only those 2 functions.. there are multiple external libraries which will be called.

Comment: Do you really need to mock those external libraries?

Comment: It seems like from everything I have read online and for unit testing functions, it seems like I have to refactor everything to use interfaces and modularize it. (example here)[https://medium.com/dm03514-tech-blog/you-are-going-to-need-it-using-interfaces-and-dependency-injection-to-future-proof-your-designs-2cf6f58db192] and (here)[https://dev.to/jonfriesen/mocking-dependencies-in-go-1h4d] and many more

Comment: Depends on your exact needs, and the code. Many times you can do with function pointers instead of interfaces. Changing the design slightly helps more. Trying to create interfaces where they're needed usually results in more idiomatic code. Putting everything into interfaces will result in Java-like code.

Comment: It is definitely much harder to write unit tests the way I have it now, since I cannot figure out how to mock the internal library calls (similar to how library calls could be mocked in python). And I do want to avoid importing a testing module for each different component (as httptest was suggested)

Comment: Again, do you need to mock all those calls? Worst case, you can declare them as unexpected function pointers and change them to test versions during testing. Most of the time, this is overkill.

Comment: I would prefer to mock all the calls for consistency. However, i'm looking into function pointers now that you mentioned it, looks interesting.. and confusing :)

Comment: The previous comment should be "unexported" instead of "unexpected". You should not change your code just to test it. Function pointers and mocking are sometimes necessary. Mostly you can do without either of those.

Comment: "it seems like I have to rewrite everything using interfaces so it can be unit tested" This is 100% untrue. Take a look at the stdlib. It contains no interfaces for testing only. And note also that the stdlib tests use basically no mocks. Adding interfaces for testing and writing mocks is the Java/C# way of unit testing, but is definitively not idiomatic and sensible for Go. Random blog post might disagree but the main reference should be the stdlib.

Comment: How else would you unit test functions without importing extra testing packages (functions that make http calls, or write and read from files)